# PUSH flag in TCP set for sending 1 MSS worth data in the middle of a big tx

Tags: tcp, push

what I mostly observed PUSH flag in TCP set to be 1 when we are sending less than 1 MSS worth data (1460) and mostly at the end of TCP tx but sometimes at the middle of a large transmission for sending 1 MSS (1460), its sometimes using the PSH flag.
Can anyone please tell me why that one is being used for tx 1460 bytes of data?

Also want to know how differently the client side TCP stack handles when it receives a data packet with PSH flag set?